# Outlook 2010 crash repair cycle

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, crash

On my computer, Outlook 2010:

1. Reports an error and then crashes.
2. The next time it's started it offers to start in safe mode, which I select, and then it crashes.
3. The third time it asks if I want to repair it which it successfully does and then...
4. on the fourth time it starts.

This cycle is repeated each time I start outlook. Any ideas why this might be happening or what to do for a permanent fix?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you attempted fully uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Or running a repair?

Comment: I haven't tried a full uninstall/reinstall but I have tried running a repair with is the 3rd point in the question.